# How To Upload Image From Media Library Programmatically?

Tags: media

I enabled latest version of media module to upload images in wysiwyg. It is working fine. There is no problem. I want to upload images programmatically from media library.

  Below is my code.

```
function test_form_upload_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
 $form['settings']['apply_now_image'] = array(
  '#type' => 'media',
  '#title' => 'Image for apply now',
 );
 $form['#submit'][] = 'test_upload_form_submit';
}

function test_upload_form_submit(&$form, $form_state) {
    global $user;
    if (!empty($form_state['values']['apply_now_image'])) {
    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['apply_now_image']);
    // Change status to permanent.
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    // Save.
    file_save($file);
    file_usage_add($file, 'user', 'user', $user->uid);
    $apply_now_image_path = file_create_url($file->uri);
    variable_set('rgit_apply_now_image', $apply_now_image_path);
    variable_set('rgit_apply_now_image1', $file->fid);
  }
}
```

But it didn't give correct answer. This is only work if the '#type' is managed_file'. It didn't work if the '#type' is media. Is any solutions there to upload images from media library.

Comment: You need to declare `$user` as global in the submit function? :

`file_usage_add($file, 'user', 'user', $user->uid);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but files uploaded via media are already permanent managed files once you get to the submit stage, I believe.

The value in the form_state array you need is `$fid = $form_state['values']['apply_now_image']['fid']);`

You can then use that in a file_load: `$file = file_load($fid);`

So your code becomes

```
$file = file_load($form_state['values']['apply_now_image']['fid']);
file_usage_add($file, 'user', 'user', $user->uid);
$apply_now_image_path = file_create_url($file->uri);
variable_set('rgit_apply_now_image', $apply_now_image_path);
variable_set('rgit_apply_now_image1', $file->fid);
```

Comment: You have described here how to upload image in drupal. I can understood this. But i want to know how to upload image using by '#type' => 'media'